# JavaScript storing search matches in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

How to store the search matches from `id="post_body"` to array?

> ```
> <textarea name="post[body]" id="post_body">
> ```
>
> --Lorem ipsum-- dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
>   --Dolore-- magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   --Duis aute-- irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum --Dolore-- eu fugiat nulla pariatur
>
> `</textarea>`

The target are all words surrounded by '--'. In Ruby, I do that with:

```
matches = tex.scan(/--(.+?)--/).flatten
matches = matches.uniq
```

In this case, the array would be:

```
matches = ["Lorem ipsum", "Dolore", "Duis aute"];
```

NB: the word "Dolore" appears twice surrounded with `--`, but in the array it should be stored only once.

Comment: You start with `document.getElementById('post_body').value.match(/--(.+?)--/)` and then you reduce it down to get unique values.

Comment: *"How to store the search matches from id="post_body" to array?"* 1. Research. 2. Experimentation. 3. Attempt. (4. If necessary **after** 1-3: Post a question showing attempt with an [MCVE](/help/mcve), describe what you expected it to do, what it's doing instead, and ask why.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    var text = document.getElementById('post_body').value;
    var res = text.match(/--\w+\s*\w*--/g);

     //remove duplicates
    uniqueArray = res.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });

     //remove "--" parts
    finalArray = uniqueArray.map(function(item) {
      return item.replace(/--/g,"");
    });

    alert(finalArray);
```

```html
<textarea name="post[body]" id="post_body">--Lorem ipsum-- dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et --Dolore-- magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. --Duis aute-- irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum --Dolore-- eu fugiat nulla pariatur</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it's so clean and illustrative!

Comment: Yes, it works for this case, when delimiters are of equal size. However, it can easily be adapted for another scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code:

```js
function contains(a, obj) {
    var i = a.length;
    while (i--) {
       if (a[i] === obj) {
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

var re = /--\s*(.*?)\s*--/g; 
var str = '--Lorem ipsum-- dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et --Dolore-- magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. --Duis aute-- irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum --Dolore-- eu fugiat nulla pariatur';
var arr = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (!contains(arr, m[1]))
    { 
        arr.push(m[1]);
    }
 }
alert(arr);
```

The regex will match the text enclosed in `--` and place the first capture group text into the array `arr` only if the value does not exist in the array (the `contains` function is taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237176/3832970)).

As for regex, `\s*` added to `--\s*(.*?)\s*--` will trim the value inside. Remove these `\s*`s if you do not need trimming.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm starting with javascript and your answer helps me to understand how it works. I keep learning.

Comment: I am glad you liked it. It is just another approach: rather than performing a post-process, I am performing logical steps that exclude it (*1. Get the captured texts, 2. Check if the text is already in an array. 3. Add the string found to the array if not found in the array.*) If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it (the up arrow on the left).